# Leg Control Bone Disappearing in Pose Mode

Tags: rigging, armature

This is pretty strange for me. I have the bottom half of my mesh in edit mode shown below. Everything seems normal here. No bones are missing.

[image]

Then once I go into pose mode, the LegCtrl.R is missing. And obviously I can't manipulate the leg easily now. What's going on?
[image]

Blend File: [image]

Comment: I tried your model, and the control bone... is there... and works... http://i.stack.imgur.com/5CbZr.png It must be something else...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have hidden the bone by pressing <kbd>H</kbd>. In pose mode press <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> to unhide all bones.

Another way is to find it in the outliner and unhide the one bone.

[image: outliner search]

Comment: Yup that was it. Never would have though of that